# Data not being displayed on first attempt

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I'm trying to get data from firestore. It was working fine. Now I want to check if the user is logged in and if he isn't then he should be navigated to login page and for this Im using authstatechanged

The problem is now the data doesnt show on the page and when I open the chrome console the data appears

I tried to call the function outside of the authstatechanged subscribe block

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl6wl.png)

[image]

The code is like this.

```
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private router: Router, private user: UserService) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (!user) {
        router.navigateByUrl('/login'); 
      }
      this.getPosts();
    });
}
```

The data should be displayed on build but it doesn't until I open console

I read somewhere that it's because of the navigation call in the subscribe clause. But I don't know how to solve it or how to navigate if the user isn't logged in.

Comment: move ur auth().subscribe to ngOnInit pls

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work. Data still appears after i hit ctrl + shift + i and not when app starts

Comment: do u have any console output of the user? Can u show ur html and the rest of the component?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an Auth Guard if you want to lock pages out from unauthorised users.

You can see an example of that here, which is part of a larger tutorial:

- https://fireship.io/lessons/angularfire-google-oauth/

The concept is that Angular provides things called Guards ([official docs example](https://angular.io/guide/router#guard-the-admin-feature)).

You use the console to generate one like:

```
ionic generate guard guards/auth
```

Then you get a snippet like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    console.log('AuthGuard#canActivate called');
    return true;
  }
}
```

As you can guess, plugging in your auth check there and returning true or false protects the url / route.

To apply this `AuthGuard` to an actual page you would do something like this in your `app-routing.module.ts` file:

```
  { 
    path: 'somepage', 
    loadChildren: './pages/somepage/somepage.module#SomePageModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
```